# SQL 2008. What permissions needed to see log file free space?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to see how much space my log file has.

What permissions need to be granted to do so?

What script shall I run to see that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE);

From BOL:

> To run DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE) requires
>   VIEW SERVER STATE permission on the
>   server.